# YA book about a girl who can calm people with magic piano playing

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read a book series a few years ago (2-4), it’s YA fantasy or sci-fi. It’s about a group of teenagers who all have unique “super powers” and are dying really young from drinking poisoned water. The girl was the only one not dying. She could play any instrument perfectly and that was her sort of magic she had. She wasn’t dying young since it was  her dad who poisoned the water. She joined a band or  something during the series. I think it was that she moved into a dorm with all the other magic people, and I vaguely remember a building starting on fire and ending up getting burned down.

I want to say they fight zombies but I don’t think they were actual zombies, maybe it was other dead, or dying super hero dudes. I also think I got it at Barns and Nobel, if that helps. It was written in English and I got it in the US.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good question to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.